# Position row headings at the bottom with pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I consulted the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable), but I could not find a way to do it. My code breaks if I try.

**Question:** Can I position the row headings at the bottom of my table?

The problem *might* be that I apply custom formatting.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=comma,
       string type,
       postproc cell content/.code={%
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{##1}%
                \ifnum\number<0
                    \cellcolor{red!-##1}##1
              \else 
                  \cellcolor{green!##1}##1
              \fi
              }},
        columns/x/.style={
            column name={},
            postproc cell content/.code={}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\caption{Correlation or something}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
x,a,b,c,d
a,90,-10.5,0,0
b,0,80,10,-10
c,0,0,-95,5
d,0,10,-5,-85
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Desired output:

```
a 90 -10.5   0   0
b  0    80  10 -10
c  0     0 -95   5
d  0    10  -5 -85
   a     b   c   d
```

Comment: Any news? Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thank you, it works perfectly well! Such a simple solution :-) I travelled for a couple of days, sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove your `head row` you could use `output empty row`. With `every last row` you could add your header to the last row (here manually), maybe somebody could help to get a better solution. But it works, if i find a better solution or someone adds a helpful comment i will edit my answer.

```
every head row/.style={ 
    output empty row,
    },
every last row/.style={
    after row={& a & b & c &d\\}
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=comma,
       string type,
       postproc cell content/.code={%
            \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{##1}%
                \ifnum\number<0
                    \cellcolor{red!-##1}##1
              \else 
                  \cellcolor{green!##1}##1
              \fi
              }},
        columns/x/.style={
            column name={},
            postproc cell content/.code={}
        },
        %%%% added
        every head row/.style={ 
        output empty row,
        },
        every last row/.style={
        after row={
             & a & b & c &d\\
                  }
        }
        %%%%%%%%%%%%5
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\caption{Correlation or something}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
x,a,b,c,d
a,90,-10.5,0,0
b,0,80,10,-10
c,0,0,-95,5
d,0,10,-5,-85
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```